# Unable to handle multiple user login - Django

Tags: django, authentication

I have ran into a small problem when trying to login 2 users in Django.
I am using default authenticate function and my code as below

```
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data1 = request.data
        username = data1['username']
        password = data1['password']
        valid_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if valid_user is not None:
            login(request, valid_user)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                            context={'request': request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key, 'user_id': user.pk, 'email': user.email})
        else:
             print("invalid")
             return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

My first login works successfully and I receive token. However if I try to login different user I am getting below response in Postman

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

Looks like I am only able to handle one user login at a time. Please help me with this

Comment: It's difficult to help you without seeing how the token key is created (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, could you confirm that you've tried logging in as the second user when the first one is *not* logged in? (I realise the answer is probably "yes", but it's nice to be sure.)

Comment: No. I want both users to be simultaneously logged in

Comment: I understand that, Rashimi. However, we need proof that the problem only happens when two users are logged in.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I got it working. I was trying to login 2 users on same device and hence issue was seen

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling your api, you dont have a csrfmiddleware token in the post body. You need to make the view [CSRF exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) when a request is made through the api.

I would suggest you use [Token Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), instead of writing your own authentication since it is safer.